# join on the basis of dynamic value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have following table.

```
[Table] coupon_sells

id,dealer_id,parent_id,modified,price 

[Table] users

id,username,password

[Table] user_profiles

id,user_id,first_name,last_name
```

Foreign keys:

```
coupon_sells[Foreign Key dealer_id,parent_id] To users
user_profiles[Foreign Key user_id ] to users
```

I want to get the total sum  of price from coupon_sells .
Condition sum onthe basis of parent_id like If parent_id is not equal to zero than sum the price field and if not zero then add sum the price with respect to the parent_id field.

I have sort the solution up to this point...

```
select case 
           when parent_id =0 
                then dealer_id 
                else parent_id 
           end 
           as test_id,sum(price),modified from coupon_sells group by test_id
```

I am getting the sum right in above query ..the problem occur when i want to get the join with users and user profiles for profile information.

Like When i run the query with join it give error:

```
select case when parent_id =0 then dealer_id else parent_id end as
test_id,sum(price),modified from coupon_sells group by test_id inner
join users  u on u.id=test_id
```

Please can any buddy help me

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
select case when u.parent_id =0 then dealer_id else u.parent_id end as test_id,
sum(price),modified from coupon_sells as cs inner join users u on u.id=test_id 
group by test_id
```

Comment: #1052 - Column 'parent_id' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: See the updated query. I have added the table aliases for column names

Comment: #1052 - Column 'modified' in field list is ambiguous